# Docking layout control for Angular2 similar to Telerik's RadDocking

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, raddocking

I am using Telerik's **RadDocking** control in Silverlight.
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/raddocking/overview2

I have searched a few docking layout controls for Angular2 but haven't come across anything which gives me something similar to the one which I mentioned above.

The closest one that I could come across was **angular2-grid**.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-grid

I was hoping Kendo will come up with such control in their latest release for Angular2. It doesn't seem to be in their roadmap either.

Even **angular/material2** hasn't started work on their layout control.
https://github.com/angular/material2

It would be of great help if somebody could point me to a good docking layout control.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [GoldenLayout](http://golden-layout.com/). We use it in my firm and that works well.
Integration with angular 2 is not really straight forward, but there is a nice discussion flow on [Github](https://github.com/deepstreamIO/golden-layout/issues/75) to explain how to integrate it with Angular 2.

Comment: That is precisely what we are using at the moment. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've created a TypeScript Version of DockSpawn and fixed a few bugs (for example use on touch devices)

available here: https://github.com/node-projects/dock-spawn-ts

Answer (score 2):

At my company we managed to use [dock-spawn](http://dock-spawn).
We were using Telerik's RadDocking in Silverlight as well. We had to do few changed in dock-spawn (such as adding support for hiding panes, adding icons to tab pages and panels). There were some issues with zone.js, that angular2 is using.

Despite all those problems it might seem worth to use, even though this library have not beed supported for last 3 years.

You can check out the [demo](http://www.dockspawn.com/demos/ide/dock_spawn_demo_ide.html) for original dock-spawn.

Below photo of he we did it:

[image]

As we are using Angular2 with typescript, we had to write our type definitions as well.

Comment: Any plan to open-source it?

Comment: it'd be great if you upload that code to github or any other site, people can refer to that as starting point.